# Functions.php: Exclude Category from "Blog"

Tags: categories, blog, exclude

So it's quite obvious to how exclude certain categories from within a template, but I don't want to have to modify 4 templates so that they ignore a certain category.

Is there a way that I can exclude a category from showing up within the "blog" set within the Reading settings? I'm assigning the blog to a Page named "Blog" ... but obviously archives and searches are going to need to be blind to this one exceeded category too.

I'd just do much rather do it within `functions.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_modify_query_exclude_category' );
function foo_modify_query_exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! $query->get( 'cat' ) )
        $query->set( 'cat', '-5' );
}
```

> So it's quite obvious to how exclude certain categories from within a
>   template, ...

Actually it's not. Are you talking about query_posts() !?

Comment: `WP_Query` or `query_posts` ... it's easy to exclude a category form the Template level. But I want to do it from within Functions.

Comment: That's exactly the solution offered by One Trick Pony...